# FSCalendar with Week scope has unintended footer-like view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, fscalendar

I have issue while using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar)

I created FSCalendar with `.week` Scope and there's unintended space at bottom of calendar.:
[image]

If I try to reduce calendar's height, its font size is also reducing and calendar looks squished.:
[image]

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    fileprivate weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
        self.calendar = calendar
        view.addSubview(calendar)
        calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        calendar.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        calendar.scope = .week
        calendar.headerHeight = 0    
    }
}
```

**I have 3 big questions.**

1. Is there any way to remove that bottom space and fit view to calendar?
2. Is FSCalendar's height should be `300`?
3. Can I use FSCalendar with AutoLayout Constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update FSCalendar's frame. It doesn't update its frame by itself when you change the scope of the calendar. You can use the following method to update its frame using a manual layout(**Already mentioned on the library's [GitHub page](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar#warning)**):

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar?, boundingRectWillChange bounds: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
    calendar?.frame = CGRect(origin: calendar?.frame.origin ?? CGPoint.zero, size: bounds.size)
    // Do other updates here
}
```

**You can also do it with AutoLayout Constraint.**